# extends another activity class and reuse listener codes to views such as buttons etc

Tags: android, android-activity, extends, code-reuse

I have created an activity called ButtonActivity that has a lot of buttons and listeners. I want to create another activity TwoButtonsActivity  to extend  ButtonActivity so that the listeners I created can be resused. 
TwoButtonsActivity  is similar  to ButtonActivity but with small changes.
Is this possible?

When I execute the code, I find that the extended activity do not respond to button click.

Here is the base activity:

```
public class ButtonActivity extends Activity {
int count = 0; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setText("Got Pressed:" + ++count);
            }
    });
}

}
```

Below is the extends Activity:

```
public class TwoButtonsActivity  extends ButtonActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




}

}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible and your code should work. Also, trying it out yourself should be faster than waiting for an answer here, so unless you really have a problem with your code, I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: When I execute the code, I find that the extended activity do not respond to button click.

Comment: are you sure you're referencing the same button ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have a  activity with listeners same below

```
  public class ButtonActivity extends Activity {
    int count = 0; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
    public void mylistener1(View v)
    {
    switch(v.getid()){
    case R.id.button:{
    //do somthings
    }break;
}}

public class TwoButtonsActivity  extends ButtonActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




}
```

}

and in layout of TwoButtonsActivity(main)  you set in tag of your button  `android:onclick="mylistener1"` 
and you should set to any button or view that you want it use this listener

Comment: if you comment setContentView(R.layout.main); in TwoButtonsActivity  your code will run and you dont need use my code